# Naming convention of creating angular modules

Tags: angularjs, naming

I was studying AngularJS from the following site,  [AngularJS](http://kirkbushell.me/when-to-use-directives-controllers-or-services-in-angular/)

They have mentioned the name of AngularJS like `my.new.module`

```
var module = angular.module( "my.new.module", [] );
```

I just want to know the meaning of `my.new.module'. Why they are using the . dot operator.

I am sharing the openstack(open source for cloud computing) source code \
https://github.com/openstack/horizon/blob/stable/kilo/horizon/static/angular/widget.module.js

```
(function () {
'use strict';
angular.module('hz.widgets', [
'hz.widget.form',
'hz.widget.help-panel',
'hz.widget.wizard',
'hz.widget.table',
'hz.widget.modal',
'hz.widget.modal-wait-spinner',
'hz.framework.bind-scope',
'hz.framework.workflow',
'hz.widget.transfer-table',
'hz.widget.charts',
'hz.widget.action-list',
'hz.widget.metadata-tree',
'hz.widget.metadata-display',
'hz.framework.validators'
])
.constant('basePath', '/static/angular/');
})();
```

**Here they are using the same thing, please describe me..**

Comment: I would guess, the autor has a C# background and likes it to separate into 'namespaces' ;) You could also write "MyNewModule".

Answer (score 0):

It is not mendatory to use dot .. its a instance name that you are providing to Module 
You can use normal name as well

```
angular.module('myApp',[]);
```

Comment: whenever you are providing value with ng-app="myApp" It will serach for attribute with directive . If values are present with it then you have define it with angular.module

Answer (score 0):

It is not an "operator" and, as alluded to in your title, merely a convention.

The dot has no special meaning, and is probably mostly borrowed from other platforms where a hierarchy of modules can make sense.

It is most often used to provide some sort of namespace to your modules, to prevent name collisions with other modules. Since, angularjs only has one global module namespace (ie. when a module is loaded, it's will override any other modules by the same name). So, to prevent collisions, it is common to name all of "mycompany"s modules like "mycompany.somemodule" and "mycompany.othermodule" for example.

In the openstack example you've added to your question. They are using the dots to delimit a namespace as I explained.

In this case they appear to have chosen the namespace `hz` (presumably short for "horizon") as their "top-level"/project namespace. Then they are further separating their namespaces into `widget` or `framework` pieces.

So, the final hierarchy of `hz.widget.form` means something like "a `form` `widget` component that is part of the `horizon` project".

But, in the end, it's just a convention to help identify where a module belongs/came from and prevent name collisions with other modules.

Comment: thanks for reply, I updated my source code please see it, I just share openstack source code, where we are using same naming convention, plz elaborate it,